# Superclass meant only to be extended, not directly instanciated

Tags: php

i am coding an OOP application in PHP. I want to have a Superclass from which other classes will inherit from.
Is there a way i can make sure the class itself can't be instantiated directly?

like:

```
class Mother {}
class Child extends Mother{}
$child = new Child();//no problemo
$mother = new Mother();//throws exception or dies
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question but `class Child extends Mother` makes me want to raise a red flag even without knowing what you're actually trying to do ;-)

Comment: can you even tell me why does it raise a red flag for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use abstract classes which only define methods but not their implementation.

```
abstract class Mother
{
    public function doSomething();
}

class Child implements Mother
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        echo 'Hello world';
    }
}

$mother = new Mother(); // won't work 
$child = new Child(); // works 
$child->doSomething(); // echoes hello world
```

Alternatively, if you need to implement the method implementation (functions do something but they can be overloaded) then you can use protected constructor.

```
class Mother 
{
    protected function __construct()
    {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
}

class Child extends Mother
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

$mother = new Mother(); // won't work, you're trying to access protected method 
$child = new Child(); // it'll work echoing "Hello World!"
```

Comment: You can also have complete method implementations in abstract classes

Comment: thanks, but i would really need a mix of the two, i want to implement a constructor and some methods in my parent class...

Comment: sorry, i didn't see your comment, i'll try it out

Comment: @André Alçada Padez - you said that the "Superclass" can't be instantiated directly. That's what protected constructor does. You can still create methods and do constructor implementation. The only thing is that the class itself MUST be extended by other classes.

Comment: IMO declaring a class abstract is the cleaner way to prevent instances. Making the constructor protected works, but is somewhat ugly

Comment: @wonk0 it's up to the person who's coding. What's important is knowing what approaches are available. You might consider it somewhat ugly, someone else might consider it good and so on, but in the end it's good to stick with one approach.

Answer (score 3):

There is [abstract](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) keyword.

```
abstract class Mother { }
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to implement a constructor and some methods in my parent class, and then overload some of them in my children